# Can I pump my damage repeatedly when using the 'Burned Over' battle move?

Tags: damage, apocalypse-world

Here's the **do battle** move from [the *Burned Over* hackbook](https://lumpley.games/burnedover/):

> When you do battle with someone, exchange harm, but first roll+Hard. On a 10+, you hold 4 against your enemy. On a 7–9, you hold 3 against them. On a miss, you hold 1 against them. If a PC, your enemy rolls simultaneously to do battle with you. If an NPC, your enemy holds 2 against you on any hit, and 3 against you on a miss.
>
> To conduct the battle, spend your hold on the following. Commit to your spends without knowing your enemy’s.
>
> • Fight for blood: Spend 1 to inflict +1harm.
>
> • Fight defensively: Spend 1 to suffer -1harm.
>
> • Fight opportunistically: Spend 1 to inflict harm on an additional enemy.
>
> • Guard someone: Spend 1 to protect an ally from 1-harm.
>
> • Seize initiative: Whoever spends more to seize initiative,
> does.
>
> [Initiative rules omitted for brevity]

Can you pump damage or defense by choosing the same "fight for blood" / "fight defensively" option multiple times? (You can't using AW2e *seize by force*, but that is a "choose" move whereas this is a "spend your hold" move.)

Comment: Not 100% sure whether to make the new tag [tag:apocalypse-world-burned-over] or just [tag:burned-over], fyi.

Comment: I suggest the former

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### You can spend as much of your hold as you want on whichever option you want.

This is true in general, though in a lot of cases where you get hold, some of the options you have to spend aren't likely to be fruitful if you take them multiple times, like asking questions whose answers aren't likely to change. But that's different from not being able to. You're always able.

Now, this is just the general idea of getting and spending hold rather than a specific explanation of *Burned Over*'s Do Battle move. While it's hard to find a rules cite to prove a negative, I can point you at [an exchange](https://lumpley.games/thebarf/index.php?topic=9270.0) over on the Lumpley games forums, where someone outlines an extended example of using Do Battle in what would previously have been a Sucker Someone situation, including spending all their hold on damage, and Vincent Baker says they got it right.

This is further clarified in [the latest draft](http://lumpley.com/index.php/window/installment/172), which replaced "hold" in *do battle* with "bid."

Comment: Good find on the hold-spending example!